# Sharepoint word search

Tags: search

I have a number of articles created in a discussion board in subsites within sharepoint. I would like to search the contents of the body of the article. For example in the body of one article there is this "fetchWorkflowProcessModel" word. Now if I search the whole word, search works. If I search Fetch*, it works. If I search fetch, it does not. If I search Workflow, it does not. Is there a way to enable sharepoint to search these words?
Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this in SharePoint search. There is no method to search for terms within terms in SharePoint unless it is the first term as suffix wildcards are not supported.

If you know the terms you could build a synonym list.